# Loading a BufferedImage in a .jar

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm currently trying working on an own game and created a Animation class, my problem is that i want the programm to be able to still find all the images when i create a jar out of it so I tried to load an Image via 
`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("player.png"));` 
but when I start the code I get a NullPointerException, i checked the location twice but the image exists and there should be no problems, can anyone help me out a bit?

Comment: At what package is your class, and what package is used for the image, getResourceAsStream without a leading / inside the path expects that the image is stored inside the same package as the class.

Comment: @ferrybig only when getResourceAsStream() is called on a Class. Here, it's call on a ClassLoader, which doesn't have any package. So this looks for the file in the default package.

Comment: Q. the simply way isn't move the image out of jar? and if the image is not inside the jar your cude simply should be "ImageIO.read("player.png").. nor?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName){

BufferedImage buff = null;
try {
    buff = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return buff;
}
```

Comment: Now I get a Illegal Argument Exception ( input == null )

Comment: @user263980 if you want a good answer, then answer to the comments you got, asking you to provide more details.

Comment: FYI: You could also use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileName))` but it equates to the same thing...

Comment: @user263980 Then the question is, where is the image stored within your Jar?  The answer provided is the correct approach